# Quick: What Format is the Date in this JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, date, encoding, formatting

I've been searching around but I can't seem to figure out what format the dates are in this JSON data.

You can see the data here: http://hypem.com/playlist/loved/beaujuda/json/3/data.js

A few examples:

```
"dateloved":1427397557
```

actual date: March 26, 2015

```
"dateloved":1426902182
```

actual date: March 20, 2015

```
"dateloved":1425067269
```

actual date: February 27, 2015

There seems to be some pattern but I'm having trouble figuring it out. I assume it's some kind of encoded date format by javascript or JSON...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's a timestamp...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called Unix time or Epoch time.

> Unix time (also known as POSIX time or Epoch time) is a system for describing instants in time, defined as the number of seconds that have elapsed since 00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), Thursday, 1 January 1970, not counting leap seconds.

See [here](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Unix_time) for more information.

BTW, You can convert it to a human-readable format [here](http://www.epochconverter.com/).